# How to send a pandas dataframe using POST method and receive it in Hug/other REST API framework? pickle.loads fails to unpickle after sending

Tags: python, pandas, request, python-requests, hug

How to send a pandas DataFrame using a `POST` method?

For example, the following [hug server](http://www.hug.rest/) listens to a `POST` requests and responds with a pickled pandas DataFrame:

```
import hug
import pickle
import traceback
import pandas as pd

@hug.post()
def call(pickle_dump):
    print(type(pickle_dump))
    try:
        df = pickle.loads(pickle_dump)
        return pickle.dumps(df.iloc[0])
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        return pickle.dumps(pd.DataFrame())
```

When the following `POST` request is made:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.randn(10,20))
r = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/call', data = {'pickle_dump':pickle.dumps(df)})
pickle.loads(r.text)
```

The server returns this traceback:

```
<class 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "post.py", line 9, in call
    df = pickle.loads(pickle_dump)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jul/2018 17:12:12] "POST /call HTTP/1.1" 200 10
```

And likewise the client returns:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-292-956952cbfca9> in <module>()
      5 r = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/call', data = {'pickle_dump':pickle.dumps(df)})
      6 
----> 7 pickle.loads(r.text)

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

This seems to be related to the fact that when a byte object is sent to the `hug` api, the bytes are converted to a str in the following way:

For example `pickle.dumps(b'test')` returns `b'\x80\x03C\x04testq\x00.'` on the client.
When it is received in the hug server, this becomes `str('\x80\x03C\x04testq\x00.')` (missing `b`). The object can be decoded back to it's original form using `pickle.loads('\x80\x03C\x04testq\x00.'.encode()[1:])`.

Applying the above process on a DataFrame results in an `UnpicklingError`:

```
> pickle.dumps(pd.DataFrame())
b'\x80\x03cpandas.core.frame\nDataFrame\nq\x00)\x81q\x01}q\x02(X\t\x00\x00\x00_metadataq\x03]q\x04X\x04\x00\x00\x00_typq\x05X\t\x00\x00\x00dataframeq\x06X\x05\x00\x00\x00_dataq\x07cpandas.core.internals\nBlockManager\nq\x08)\x81q\t(]q\n(cpandas.core.indexes.base\n_new_Index\nq\x0bcpandas.core.indexes.base\nIndex\nq\x0c}q\r(X\x04\x00\x00\x00nameq\x0eNX\x04\x00\x00\x00dataq\x0fcnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\nq\x10cnumpy\nndarray\nq\x11K\x00\x85q\x12C\x01bq\x13\x87q\x14Rq\x15(K\x01K\x00\x85q\x16cnumpy\ndtype\nq\x17X\x02\x00\x00\x00O8q\x18K\x00K\x01\x87q\x19Rq\x1a(K\x03X\x01\x00\x00\x00|q\x1bNNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK?tq\x1cb\x89]q\x1dtq\x1ebu\x86q\x1fRq h\x0bh\x0c}q!(h\x0eNh\x0fh\x10h\x11K\x00\x85q"h\x13\x87q#Rq$(K\x01K\x00\x85q%h\x1a\x89]q&tq\'bu\x86q(Rq)e]q*]q+}q,X\x06\x00\x00\x000.14.1q-}q.(X\x06\x00\x00\x00blocksq/]q0X\x04\x00\x00\x00axesq1h\nustq2bub.'
```

Reversing the pickle

```
pickle.loads('\x80\x03cpandas.core.frame\nDataFrame\nq\x00)\x81q\x01}q\x02(X\t\x00\x00\x00_metadataq\x03]q\x04X\x04\x00\x00\x00_typq\x05X\t\x00\x00\x00dataframeq\x06X\x05\x00\x00\x00_dataq\x07cpandas.core.internals\nBlockManager\nq\x08)\x81q\t(]q\n(cpandas.core.indexes.base\n_new_Index\nq\x0bcpandas.core.indexes.base\nIndex\nq\x0c}q\r(X\x04\x00\x00\x00nameq\x0eNX\x04\x00\x00\x00dataq\x0fcnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\nq\x10cnumpy\nndarray\nq\x11K\x00\x85q\x12C\x01bq\x13\x87q\x14Rq\x15(K\x01K\x00\x85q\x16cnumpy\ndtype\nq\x17X\x02\x00\x00\x00O8q\x18K\x00K\x01\x87q\x19Rq\x1a(K\x03X\x01\x00\x00\x00|q\x1bNNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK?tq\x1cb\x89]q\x1dtq\x1ebu\x86q\x1fRq h\x0bh\x0c}q!(h\x0eNh\x0fh\x10h\x11K\x00\x85q"h\x13\x87q#Rq$(K\x01K\x00\x85q%h\x1a\x89]q&tq\'bu\x86q(Rq)e]q*]q+}q,X\x06\x00\x00\x000.14.1q-}q.(X\x06\x00\x00\x00blocksq/]q0X\x04\x00\x00\x00axesq1h\nustq2bub.'.encode()[1:])
```

Results in:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-314-7082d60a5569> in <module>()
----> 1 pickle.loads('\x80\x03cpandas.core.frame\nDataFrame\nq\x00)\x81q\x01}q\x02(X\t\x00\x00\x00_metadataq\x03]q\x04X\x04\x00\x00\x00_typq\x05X\t\x00\x00\x00dataframeq\x06X\x05\x00\x00\x00_dataq\x07cpandas.core.internals\nBlockManager\nq\x08)\x81q\t(]q\n(cpandas.core.indexes.base\n_new_Index\nq\x0bcpandas.core.indexes.base\nIndex\nq\x0c}q\r(X\x04\x00\x00\x00nameq\x0eNX\x04\x00\x00\x00dataq\x0fcnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\nq\x10cnumpy\nndarray\nq\x11K\x00\x85q\x12C\x01bq\x13\x87q\x14Rq\x15(K\x01K\x00\x85q\x16cnumpy\ndtype\nq\x17X\x02\x00\x00\x00O8q\x18K\x00K\x01\x87q\x19Rq\x1a(K\x03X\x01\x00\x00\x00|q\x1bNNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK?tq\x1cb\x89]q\x1dtq\x1ebu\x86q\x1fRq h\x0bh\x0c}q!(h\x0eNh\x0fh\x10h\x11K\x00\x85q"h\x13\x87q#Rq$(K\x01K\x00\x85q%h\x1a\x89]q&tq\'bu\x86q(Rq)e]q*]q+}q,X\x06\x00\x00\x000.14.1q-}q.(X\x06\x00\x00\x00blocksq/]q0X\x04\x00\x00\x00axesq1h\nustq2bub.'.encode()[1:])

UnpicklingError:
```

**I am open to using any framework which will allow me to send and receive a pandas DataFrame using `HTTP` requests.**

Both the server and the client are run in the same environment with identical package versions.

How to send and receive a pandas DataFrame using `HTTP` methods?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems like b64 encoding the pickled string seems to alleviate the issue. For brevity, I will use an example to demonstrate.

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 1, 2, 3]})
>>> df
   a
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
```

Now, let's pickle the object to a bytes-like string, and then b64encode the pickled string:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> pickled = pickle.dumps(df)
>>> import base64
>>> pickled_b64 = base64.b64encode(pickled)
>>> pickled_b64
b'gANjcGFuZGFzLmNvcmUuZnJhbWUKRGF0YUZyYW1lCnEAKYFxAX1xAihYCQAAAF9tZXRhZGF0YXEDXXEEWAQAAABfdHlwcQVYCQAAAGRhdGFmcmFtZXEGWAUAAABfZGF0YXEHY3BhbmRhcy5jb3JlLmludGVybmFscwpCbG9ja01hbmFnZXIKcQgpgXEJKF1xCihjcGFuZGFzLmNvcmUuaW5kZXhlcy5iYXNlCl9uZXdfSW5kZXgKcQtjcGFuZGFzLmNvcmUuaW5kZXhlcy5iYXNlCkluZGV4CnEMfXENKFgEAAAAbmFtZXEOTlgEAAAAZGF0YXEPY251bXB5LmNvcmUubXVsdGlhcnJheQpfcmVjb25zdHJ1Y3QKcRBjbnVtcHkKbmRhcnJheQpxEUsAhXESQwFicROHcRRScRUoSwFLAYVxFmNudW1weQpkdHlwZQpxF1gCAAAATzhxGEsASwGHcRlScRooSwNYAQAAAHxxG05OTkr/////Sv////9LP3RxHGKJXXEdWAEAAABhcR5hdHEfYnWGcSBScSFoC2NwYW5kYXMuY29yZS5pbmRleGVzLnJhbmdlClJhbmdlSW5kZXgKcSJ9cSMoaA5OWAUAAABzdGFydHEkSwBYBAAAAHN0b3BxJUsEWAQAAABzdGVwcSZLAXWGcSdScShlXXEpaBBoEUsAhXEqaBOHcStScSwoSwFLAUsEhnEtaBdYAgAAAGk4cS5LAEsBh3EvUnEwKEsDWAEAAAA8cTFOTk5K/////0r/////SwB0cTJiiUMgAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAwAAAAAAAABxM3RxNGJhXXE1aAtoDH1xNihoDk5oD2gQaBFLAIVxN2gTh3E4UnE5KEsBSwGFcTpoGoldcTtoHmF0cTxidYZxPVJxPmF9cT9YBgAAADAuMTQuMXFAfXFBKFgGAAAAYmxvY2tzcUJdcUN9cUQoWAgAAABtZ3JfbG9jc3FFY2J1aWx0aW5zCnNsaWNlCnFGSwBLAUsBh3FHUnFIWAYAAAB2YWx1ZXNxSWgsdWFYBAAAAGF4ZXNxSmgKdXN0cUtidWIu'
```

So the 64encoded string is also a bytes-like string, but it doesn't contain the hex escape sequences so when it gets converted to a string, the string is still preserved when encoding it to bytes.

Now, let's mimic what `hug` does to the string, as you have noted:

```
>>> hug_pickled_str = pickled_b64.decode('utf-8')
>>> hug_pickled_str
'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'
```

Now to make the string consumable on the server-side:

```
>>> ss_df = pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(hug_pickled_str.encode()))
>>> ss_df
   a
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
```

Therefore, you would need to base64 encode your pickled string and pass that string as the data to your API.